Source on Hilbert's theorem about the embedding of hyperbolic space
Is there a book covering (in detail) Hilbert's theorem on the impossibility of an isometric immersion of the hyperbolic plane in $\mathbb R³$ and also Nash's theorem which states that hyperbolic space can be embedded in $\mathbb R^N$ for some $N \in \mathbb N$. I need this book for reference in my thesis but I unfortunately couldn't find a good source.

Nash's embedding theorem is not special to hyperbolic space, it holds for any Riemannian manifold. Look up the Nash embedding theorem.

You can read proofs of both nonexistence of isometric immersions of the hyperbolic plane in $\mathbb R^3$ and Nash's Isometric Embedding Theorem in:
Han, Qing; Hong, Jia-Xing, Isometric embedding of Riemannian manifolds in Euclidean spaces, Mathematical Surveys and Monographs 130. Providence, RI: American Mathematical Society (AMS) (ISBN 0-8218-4071-1/hbk). xiv, 260 p. (2006). ZBL1113.53002.
But make sure you have sufficient background in differential geometry and differential topology if you want to read this book.
